# Chrome extension context menu with custom context

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I created a context menu in my chome extension as a checkbox, I am successfull to create the menu which will be visible only for editable field.

The problem is I need to display menu as checked, according to a data attribute in the textfield(focused element). With the following code, it is displaying checked in a global level(means if i checked the menu in one page/elemebt is will remains checked for other page/elements as well.)

How can I make it checked/unchecked according to the element's data attribute ?

```
var addinMenu = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "My Addin Menu",
    "contexts": ["editable"]
});
var disableOrEnable = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "type": "checkbox",
    "title": "Disable",
    "parentId": addinMenu,
    "id": "myaddin_disable",
    "checked": true,
    "contexts": ["editable"],
    "onclick": disableOrEnableMyAddin
});
```

Comment: Related: [Showing context menu buttons only when right-clicked on classes that start with “Story”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829677/showing-context-menu-buttons-only-when-right-clicked-on-classes-that-start-with) (the example works with a class name, but tweaking the code to use a data attribute shouldn't be too difficult)

Comment: Thanks, I will try to tweak this one and let you know.

Answer (score 3):

Call [`chrome.contextMenus.update()`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#method-update) when the menu properties should change, e.g.:

```
chrome.contextMenus.update(
  disableOrEnable,
  { type: 'checkbox', checked: false });
```

It looks like you can catch the `oncontextmenu` event and make changes that are immediately reflected in the posted menu (but I see from Rob W's comment there may be a [race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202896/creating-dynamic-context-menu-in-chrome-extension-is-failing) with that).  This works for me:

```
var contextMenu = chrome.contextMenus.create(
  {
    type: 'checkbox',
    title: 'how now brown cow',
    checked: false,
    contexts: ['all']
  });

var element = document.getElementById('hello');
element.addEventListener(
  'mouseover',
  function(e) {
    element.setAttribute('underMouse', 'true');
  });
element.addEventListener(
  'mouseout',
  function(e) {
    element.setAttribute('underMouse', '');
  });

window.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
  chrome.contextMenus.update(
    contextMenu,
    {
      type: 'checkbox',
      checked: element.getAttribute('underMouse') == 'true'
    });
}
```

If you're just interested in the currently focused textfield you could also just change your menu in `focus` and `blur` events.  You may also want to check out the `'editable'` option to the `contexts` menu property (not sure what that does but sounds like it might restrict the menu to text input elements).

Comment: This will update the status everywhere, not with respect to one control, I need to display enable/disable in different element. Lets say I have two textfield in one page, If check the menu in one of them , it should not display checked for the other one when I open context menu.

Comment: I see.  Can you not catch the [right-click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500743/js-detect-right-click-without-jquery-inline) (or other context menu event) and change it?  I'm not sure if it will update while the menu is already being displayed.

Comment: Enter / leave events are not there it seems, only one hook is available to us is after doing the action. in Firefox, we can write our own context to display menu.