# Right Click Menu Event using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, right-click

I'm working on a new project and I need to create an event where a menu list will show up once I right click on a label. Any idea how to do this?

When you click on a list from the menu box, a dialog box will appear. I do know how to create a dialog box but my problem is the right click event.

```
var createDialog = function(){

dialog = new Ext.LayoutDialog(id+'container', {
        title: "DXFエクスポート",
        width: 350,
        height: 400,
        shadow: true,
        proxyDrag: false,
        resizable: true,
        modal: false,
        autoScroll:true,
        center: {
            autoScroll:true
        },
        south: {
            height: 60
        }
    });
```

I hope someone can give me an idea how to do mouse events.

Comment: it's called mousevent [right click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event)

Comment: You should google for "javascript context menu" to see some examples, and check answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500743/js-detect-right-click-without-jquery-inline

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS: detect right click without jQuery (inline)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500743/js-detect-right-click-without-jquery-inline)